# Select list (dropdown) in HAML

Tags: php, yii, haml

I'm having trouble producing a traditional HTML dropdown box in HAML. I'm using the Yii HAML extension, so I'm sure if its a quirk with that specifically.

This is the HAML I'm using ...

```
%select
   %option one
   %option two
   %option three
```

This is the HTML output I'm trying to get ...

```
<select>
   <option>one</option>
   <option>two</option>
   <option>three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I get an "invalid indentation" HAML error.  I've tried this on a testing service http://rendera.heroku.com/examples/haml and it came out fine.

Comment: again I think this is an issue with the PHP or Yii version of HAML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your indent is off by one space. It's two spaces, not three.

```
%select
  %option one
  %option two
  %option three
```