# Dropdown menu in HAML

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, haml

I have just started adopting Haml, and I have encountered a problem that I cannot seem to find a solution for. It might just be because I do not know the right html term to use in my search, but this have led me to posting here.

How do you write a line like this in haml:

```
<ul id="drop" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown">
```

Or look at this link to see full context.
https://gist.github.com/czepluch/7817008

Comment: Take a  look at this link <br>


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746870/select-list-dropdown-in-haml

Comment: I do not really see how that relates to my question? My problem is the 'data-dropdown-content' part. How do I do something like that in haml?

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing there are a couple of issues here – creating boolean attributes, and attributes with `-` in them.

In order to get a [boolean attribute](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#boolean_attributes) (i.e. the attribute doesn’t appear with a value) you use `true` as the value in your Haml. You also need to ensure the format is `html4` or `html5` (the default is `html5`).

You can’t use an unquoted symbol as the attribute value, since the hyphen will be interpreted as a minus, you will need to use a string.

So combining these the Haml you want is something like this:

```haml
%ul#drop.f-dropdown{"data-dropdown-class" => true}
```

which produces:

```html
<ul class='f-dropdown' data-dropdown-class id='drop'></ul>
```

Haml also has support for [custom data attributes](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#html5_custom_data_attributes) using a hash, so you could do:

```haml
%ul#drop.f-dropdown{:data => {"dropdown-class" => true}}
```

which produces the same result. This doesn’t help much in this case, it is more useful where you have multiple `data-*` attributes – you can put them in a hash and you only need to specify the `data` prefix once.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It gave me understanding of how it works. I still cannot get the dropdown menu to work, but I do not get an error anymore. Now the button for the dropdown just doesn't show anymore. Dont know what is worse. hehe. But thanks.

Comment: I have now been trying for two days to get the dropdown to work, but there still seems to be a problem. I have made a gist with the entire haml code for the top bar. I hope someone will take a look at it and help me in the right direction. https://gist.github.com/czepluch/7883205